# Update sum of records

Tags: mysql, sql-server, group-by, sql-update, sum

I have this table called 'bill' as shown below:

```
Cust_id |Bill_amt |Brand |Skincare |Toner |BrandA |BrandB |A_skincare |A_toner |B_skincare |B_toner
001     |100      |A     |50       |50  |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
001     |200      |A     |150      |50  |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
001     |500      |B     |355      |145 |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
009     |325      |B     |125      |200 |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
```

I want to update this table into a new table called 'txn' which have these columns included:

```
Cust_id |Value  |BrandA |BrandB |A_skincare |A_toner |B_skincare |B_toner
001     |800    |300    |500    |200        |100     |355        |145 
009     |325    |NULL   |325    |NULL       |NULL    |125        |200
```

Value is the sum of Brand A and B within that customer. 
How do I update the 'bill' table into 'txn' table and just show distinct customer?
Apologies for the untidiness and thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
create table txn as(select DISTINCT custid,sum(BrandA+BrandB) as value,BrandA,BrandB,A_skincare,B_skincare,B_toner) from bill
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

FOR **MYSQL::**

```
UPDATE txn t 
INNER JOIN (SELECT b.Cust_id, SUM(b.Bill_amt) AS `Value`, 
                   SUM(IF(Brand = 'A', b.Bill_amt, 0)) BrandA, SUM(IF(Brand = 'B', b.Bill_amt, 0))BrandB, 
                   SUM(IF(Brand = 'A', b.Skincare, 0)) A_skincare, SUM(IF(Brand = 'B', b.Skincare, 0)) B_skincare, 
                   SUM(IF(Brand = 'A', b.Toner, 0)) A_toner, SUM(IF(Brand = 'B', b.Toner, 0)) B_toner
            FROM bill b 
            GROUP BY b.Cust_id 
           ) AS A ON t.Cust_id = A.Cust_id 
SET t.Value = A.Value, t.BrandA = A.BrandA, t.BrandB = A.BrandB, 
    t.A_skincare = A.A_skincare, t.B_skincare = A.B_skincare, 
    t.A_toner = A.A_toner, t.B_toner = A.B_toner
```

FOR **SQL SERVER::**

```
UPDATE t 
SET t.Value = A.Value, t.BrandA = A.BrandA, t.BrandB = A.BrandB, 
    t.A_skincare = A.A_skincare, t.B_skincare = A.B_skincare, 
    t.A_toner = A.A_toner, t.B_toner = A.B_toner 
FROM txn t 
INNER JOIN (SELECT b.Cust_id, SUM(b.Bill_amt) AS `Value`, 
                   SUM(IF(Brand = 'A', b.Bill_amt, 0)) BrandA, SUM(IF(Brand = 'B', b.Bill_amt, 0))BrandB, 
                   SUM(IF(Brand = 'A', b.Skincare, 0)) A_skincare, SUM(IF(Brand = 'B', b.Skincare, 0)) B_skincare, 
                   SUM(IF(Brand = 'A', b.Toner, 0)) A_toner, SUM(IF(Brand = 'B', b.Toner, 0)) B_toner
            FROM bill b 
            GROUP BY b.Cust_id 
           ) AS A ON t.Cust_id = A.Cust_id
```